# Javascript (JQuery) keyboard hijack problem

Tags: jquery, keydown

I'm making a typing tutor program using javascript. Everything is going well except that if activates browser hotkeys which disrupts the functionality of the program. When I press the single quote in Firefox it triggers "Quick find (links only)" short cut and in all browsers when I press space the page scrolls down a page. Everything is working fine outside of this. Here's the code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    executeType();
});
</script>
```

And the code I am using to capture the keyboard (simplified, but tested):

```
function executeType() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
           alert(event.keyCode);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried having your event handler return `false`?

Comment: I couldn't get return false to work with .keydown(), but it worked once I switched to .keypress() and used returned false, as suggested in the selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop keypresses from having their normal default behaviour, you should `return false` from the event handler.

Any keypresses that you pick up and do something with, you should cancel the default action for. However, be careful not to over-block by picking up things like ctrl-key combinations which the user is likely to want to continue to use for browser shortcuts.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey)
        return;
    // do something with keypress
    return false;
});
```

(This still blocks single-key actions such as page-up/down and F5-to-refresh though, which isn't great. You'd generally look at the key code to detect only the keys you wanted to handle yourself, letting the rest through. Aside: I used keypress here rather than keydown since Opera doesn't support preventing the default action on keydown.)